# Loop on SPARK DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Environment: Spark 2.4 + Scala 2.11.12

I have DF named DF_ACTION

```
--------------------------------------
process  |action_step|MAC|action_name
----------------------------------------
HighError|1          |PQR| callAPI A
---------------------------------------
HighError|2          |PQR| callAPI B 
---------------------------------------
HighError|1          |XYZ| callAPI A
---------------------------------------
HighError|2          |XYZ| callAPI B 
---------------------------------------
Restart  |1          |1BC| callAPI X
---------------------------------------
Restart  |2          |1BC| callAPI Y
```

Now I am trying to call some functions and do some tasks depending on the value of DF_ACTION

```
for (i<-DF_ACTION){
  If (i.process==="HighError" ) and (i.step_no===1)  // error in this line
{
     call function A
     call function B
  }

  sleep(20 minutes)

  If (i.process==="HighError" ) and (i.step_no===2)  // error in this line
{
     call function p
     call function q
  }    
}
```

Hope I am able to explain problem. Thanks in advance 
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the syntax you're trying will not work as you cannot compare a DataFrame or column to a string or int

You can first collect the data and then loop through them so now you're comparing similar data types.
Remember collect is not a good idea to use if it is a very big dataset

If I understood your question correctly below can be a sample code for you to try on

```
val cll = df_action.select("process", "action_step").collect

for(cl <- cll){
    if (cl(0) == "HighError" && cl(1) == 1){
       call function A
       call function B
    }
    if (cl(0) == "HighError" && cl(1) == 2){
       call function p
       call function q
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: after call to `collect`, you're collecting all the data in the dataframe on your driver, so if `DF_ACTION ` is rather big, you may get OOM errors.

Comment: @RayanRal Yeah I have already mentioned in the solution above